# Create a link to a OneNote page that does not bring up the web browser

Tags: microsoft-onenote

I am following the directions to create "[Keyboard shortcuts for fast access to favorite OneNote pages](https://web.archive.org/web/20160214140326/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/david_rasmussen/archive/2006/06/13/629466.aspx)", but my Live SkyDrive stored one note gets brought up in the OneNote Web App instead of the OneNote application.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me in ON2010, which is where I first saw this problem. ON2007 didn't do this as I recall, and I don't have ON2013 handy to test.

Simple answer, although not so convenient:

1. In OneNote, right-click on a page tab in a SkyDrive notebook and choose "Copy Link to Page".
2. Open Notepad, and choose Edit -> Paste. You should see two lines of text. (*It may look like more than two lines if you have Word Wrap turned on, so maybe turn that off from Notepad's Format menu.*) The first line starts with "https://" and is a link to the notebook on SkyDrive. The **second** line starts with "onenote:" and is a link to the page on your local machine.
3. Highlight the **second** line of text that starts with "onenote:" in its entirety.
4. Copy to the clipboard
5. Switch back to ON and highlight the text you want to use as the link.
6. Press Ctrl-K or choose Insert -> Link from the ribbon.
7. Paste the link into the Address field in the Link dialog, then press OK.

Answer (score 0):

The slightly less cumbersome way is:

In Desktop OneNote: Right Click "copy link to" page or paragraph

STILL IN Desktop OneNote: Paste that link into a page

Right click that newly-created link and select "copy link"

If you paste that outside of OneNote it's just the local version (OneNote:****), you don't have to scrub the web link off the front.